# Java Maven project create background task

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, background-task

I am new to creating background tasks in Java. I have a situation in which I need to create a background task that runs every 10 mins to fetch new documents from the Google drive. I have created a Google App Engine project using maven on which I am working. Can anyone please suggest me some tutorials and any guidance how to achieve this task.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case , you should look into the Quartz scheduling library. which does what you want.

```
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/
```

You can add the quartz dependency in your maven pom.xml and write the code in java to schedule a job to do what you want to achieve.

I hope this helps.Please do let me know if you need any further help with this.

Comment: will let you know once I will be finishing my demo

Comment: actually, quartz scheduler is a really bad choice on app engine unless you have an app that runs in basic scaling mode with a single instance always running. If that is not the case, you should check out [appengine's cron service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron).